# Math Trig Question

Tags: trigonometry

If $\tan x =-\frac{3}{4}$ and $x$ is obtuse, evaluate $\sin 2x$

Comment: Please include some context, such as your idea about solving the problem, so that a Reader can better grasp what difficulty you are having with this exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

You can try to draw a triangle with side $3,4,5$
And then use the identity $$\sin 2x=2\sin x \cos x $$

Comment: ty i got the answer -24/25

Comment: 2(3/5)(-4/5) which i then evaluated

Answer (score 0):

$$
\sin2x=2\sin x\cos x=
\frac{2\sin x\cos x}{\sin^2x+\cos^2x}=
\frac{2\dfrac{\sin x\cos x}{\sin^2x}}
  {\dfrac{\sin^2x+\cos^2x}{\sin^2x}}=
\frac{2\tan x}{1+\tan^2x}=…
$$